# Conway, proving a function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be an open subset of the complex plane and $ f: G \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ an analytic function.

Define $ \Phi: G \times G \Rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by 
$$ \Phi(z,w) = (f(z)-f(w))/(z-w) $$ if $ z \neq w$ and $$ \Phi(w,w) = f'(w) .$$
Show that for each $w$ in $G$, $ z \rightarrow \Phi(z,w)$ is analytic.

My attempt is this, 
So fix $w$.  For $ z \neq w $, the function $ f(z) - f(w)$ and $ 1/(z-w)$ is analytic since $f(z)$ is analytic in $G$.  So I can conclude that $ \Phi(z,w) $ is analytic in $ G - \{w\}$.  But how do I show the function is analytic at $w$?

I try to compute what is the derivative at $w$ by def, I get 
$$ \Phi'(w,w) = \lim_{z \rightarrow w} \frac{ \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} - f'(w) }{z-w} $$. But as $z$ approaches $w$ I would get 0 top and bottom, so I really don't know what to do next.  Thank you.

Edit: 2nd attempt using copper.hat idea.

So by what I state above in my original question, I only need to show that $\Phi(z,w)$ is analytic at $ w$.

Since $f$ is analytic at $w$, then $ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (z-w)^n $ for $ z \in B(w;R) $ and $ f(w) = a_0 $.

So for $z \neq w$,  $$ \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-w)^{n-1} ~~~~~~~~(1)$$
So we see that the series (1) above converge for $ 0 < |z-w| < R $.
But this series also converge at w, since $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(w-w)^{n-1} = a_1 = f'(w) $$. Thus this series converge for $ z \in B(w;R) $, hence its radius of convergence is equal or greater than R.  Therefore, the series (1) is analytic in $B(w;R)$.

Since by def, $ \Phi(w,w) = f'(w) $ and we just show for $ z \neq w,  \frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-w)^{n-1}$,  we see that 
$$ \Phi(z,w) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(z-w)^{n-1} $$ so $\Phi(z,w) $ is analytic at w as needed.

Comment: You can save some typing with \to which becomes $\to$, instead of \Rightarrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z) = {f(z)-f(w) \over z-w}$ for $z \neq w$. Note that $g$ has an
isolated singularity at $z=w$.

Then $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=w$ **iff** $\lim_{z \to w} (z-w) g(w) = 0$.

Hence $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=w$ and so there is a function $\tilde{g}$ that is analytic on $G$ and $g(z) = \tilde{g}(z)$ for $z \neq w$.

By taking limits, we see that $\lim_{z \to w} g(z) = f'(w)$, hence
$\tilde{g}(z) = \begin{cases} g(z), & z \neq q \\
f'(w), & z=w \end{cases}$.

Since $\phi(z,w) = \tilde{g}(z)$ we have the desired result.

Comment: thank you, copper.hat.  I thought we have to do some epsilon delta proof but it turns out so simple. thank you again.

Comment: Hello copper.hat.  I just want to ask if you can check my reasoning again, I just edit the question,  I understand your proof, but since I didn't learn singularity yet, ( it's actually the next chapter in Conway), I did use your idea to construct my reasoning using what I already learned.  thank you very much.

Comment: @Khoata: It looks good, note that the power series (1) is valid for all $z$ such that $|z-w| < R$. Since this equals $\phi(z,w)$ you are finished.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've been reading Conway by myself at home so I got stuck quite a bit.  I appreciare your help.

Comment: @Khoata: Glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is analytic on the open set $G,$ and $w\in G,$ so $f$ is equal to its power series expansion about $w$ on an open ball $B$ centered at $w$, of positive radius,  such that $B\subset G.$ So for $z\in B$ with $z\ne w$  we  have $$f(z)=f(w)+(z-w)f'(w)+ (z-w)^2f''(w)/2+ O(|z-w|^3)$$ as $|z-w|\to 0.$ .Hence $(\Phi(z,w)-f'(w))(z-w)^{-1}=f''(w)/2 +O(|z-w|)$, converging to $f''(w)/2$ as $z\to w.$