# How to show that a continuous function analytic in a deleted neighbourhood is analytic in the entire neighbourhood?

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity, analytic-functions

Suppose
$$
F(z)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}, & z\ne a\\[2ex]
\quad f'(a), & z=a
\end{cases}
$$
Here $f$ is analytic on a simply connected domain $D$ containing $a$. Clearly, $F$ is analytic on $D\setminus\{a\}$ since it is a composition of analytic functions. I want to show that $F$ is analytic on $D$.

I tried  to prove it using the definition. To show analyticity on $D$, we can show differentiability at $a$. So I tried evaluating the limit:
$$
\lim_{z\to a} \dfrac{F(z)-F(a)}{z-a}
$$

Substituting $F(z)$,
$$
\lim_{z\to a} \dfrac{\dfrac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}-f'(a)}{z-a}
$$

Since $f$ is analytic, $\lim_{z\to a}\dfrac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}=f'(a)$. It's been a long time since I evaluated limits but I know that I can't just substitute this in the numerator since I need to account for the denominator as well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And what if you try L'Hospital in that last step?

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, L'Hospital never came to my mind ^_^. Anyways I'm not very comfortable with using L'Hospital rule even for real limits.

Comment: @Jamal A pity, because L'Hospital is more about having Taylor series (which is one of the equivalente definitions of complex analytic function) than about being merely differentiable.

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh I see. I will definitely strengthen my skills there then.

Comment: According to Riemann's theorem on removable singularities it suffices to show that $F$ is continuous at $z=a$, compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1622096/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $a$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-a)^n$, then $a_0=f(a)$ and therefore near $a$ you have$$F(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(a)}{z-a}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(z-a)^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n+1}(z-a)^n.$$

Comment: I think $F$ and $f$ should be swapped.

Comment: @Jamāl Yes. It's done.

Comment: Thanks. Very clean proof. I keep trying to use the blunt definition for analyticity ie. differentiable in a neighbourhood instead of the much powerful Taylor series expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is analytic on $D$, we have for $z\in D$ and $a\in D$

$$\begin{align}
f(z)-f(a)-f'(a)(z-a)&=\int_a^z\int_a^{z'} f''(w)\,dw\,dz'\\\\
&=\int_a^z f''(w)(z-w)\,dw\tag1
\end{align}$$

where the integrals in $(1)$ are taken along rectifiable curves that lie in $D$.

---

Next, dividing $(1)$ by $(z-a)^2$ and letting $z\to a$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{z\to a}\frac{f(z)-f(a)-f'(a)(z-a)}{(z-a)^2}&=\lim_{z\to a}\frac1{(z-a)^2}\int_a^z f''(w)(z-w)\,dw\\\\
&=f''(a)\lim_{z\to a}\frac1{(z-a)^2}\int_a^z (z-w)\,dw\\\\
&+\lim_{z\to a}\frac1{(z-a)^2}\int_a^z (f''(w)-f''(a))(z-w)\,dw\\\\
&=\frac12 f''(a)\\\\
&+\lim_{z\to a}\frac1{(z-a)^2}\int_a^z (f''(w)-f''(a))(z-w)\,dw\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

We will now show that the limit on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is $0$.

First, since $f''$ is continuous, for any given $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a number $0<|z-a|<\delta$ such that $|f''(z)-f''(a)|<\varepsilon$ whenever $|z-a|<\delta$.

We also take $\delta$ so small that we can parameterize $w\in D$ as $w=a+(z-a)t$, $t\in[0,1]$.  Then, we have the estimates for $|z-a|<\delta$

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^z (f''(w)-f''(a))(z-w)\,dw\right|&\le  \int_0^1 |f''(a+(z-a)t)-f''(a)| (1-t)|z-a|^2\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{\varepsilon}2|z-a|^2
\end{align}$$

---

Putting it all together yields the coveted result

$$\lim_{z\to a}\frac{F(z)-F(a)}{z-a}=\frac12 f''(a)$$

from which we find that $F$ is analytic on $D$.  And we are done!

Comment: I was curious about what the limit was. I tried evaluating using L'Hospital but in vain. Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 1):

1. Since $F$ is analytic in $D \setminus \{a\}$, the function $F$ has an isolated singularity at $a$.
2. From $ \lim_{z \to a}F(z)=f'(a)$ we see that the singularity at $a$ is a removabvle singularity (Riemann !).